# Call MATLAB functions using Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a full functional MATLAB program, and I need to make a Python script where I can call a specific function from the MATLAB program. I am using Python version 2.7, and I did try to install pymat, but it didn't work for some reason.

I did look into other questions where all recommend pymat, but it is old and not maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no personal experience with it, but the project page for [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) seems to indicate it will fit your needs.

From the project page:

> Mlabwrap is a high-level python to MATLAB® bridge that lets MATLAB look like a normal Python library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) which is a Python-based system, and it has an [interface to MATLAB](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/matlab.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [pymatbridge](https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge). It's a library that allows you to send variables (for example, NumPy `ndarray` class instances) between MATLAB and Python. It also has an implementation of a MATLAB 'magic' function for [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the MATLAB officially provided `matlab.engine` could be the one you want. Refer to ["Call User Script and Function from Python"](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html) and other instructions on the official website.
It runs well for most cases on my ubuntu16.04 with python3.5.2(jupyter-notebook) + MATLAB R2016b.